# ValueInjecter custom mapping doesn't work on custom properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc, valueinjecter

I have this code:

```
 Mapper.AddMap<Product, DetailsVM>(src =>
 {
            var res = new DetailsVM();
            res.InjectFrom(src); // maps properties with same name and type
            res.test = "asd";
            return res;
  });

  productVM.InjectFrom(test);
```

I have everything working and this is my VM:

```
public int ProductId { get; set; }
public decimal Cost { get; set; }
public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
public int OnHandQty { get; set; }

public ProductPicture thumb { get; set; }
public ProductPicture main { get; set; }

public string test { get; set; }
```

the actual model doesn't have the property `test`, I simply want to set `test` to any string. how do I do it? I keep on getting `null` whenever i try to map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to call `Mapper.Map` instead of `InjectFrom`, 
`InjectFrom` is not affected by `Mapper.AddMap`

Comment: Do you have any samples of how to do that?